# Regular expression for extracting HTML tag groups from a web page

Tags: html, regex

I want to extract (match) content from one or more tag groups. Example:

```
<div class="cb main"><div class="header">...content...</div></div>
<div class="cb sub"><div class="subtitle">...content...</div></div>
<div class="note">...content...</div>
<div class="cb footer><span class="highlight">...content...</span></div>
```

In the above example I want to be able to match against tags that have at least class = "cb", including that tag and its matching end tag and all tags and content in-between. Three tags are matched in the example.

Comment: How about this `<div class="cb main"><div class="header"><!-- </div></div>-->...content...</div></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. The notion of "in a class" is too complex for  regexp

You should use XPath expression instead. You will have better results:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'cb')]
```

Important: dont forget the // . it's not a comment.